# C++ threads and classess

Tags: c++, multithreading

I've been working recently on a threaded program , simple stuff - it works.
I would like to improve it now or rewrite it in object oriented way.

I'm using Code::Blocks and as I learned I'm storing classes in separate files. There I have the functions prototyped in the .h file.
The thing that I wanted to ask is:
Where should I start the threads ? Where should I join them ? In the "main.cpp" file ?
Can you provide some kind of simple example on how to start such threads if I'm storing classes and funct. in different file ?
Thanks
my class file

```
#include "fooCheck.h"
#include <iostream>

fooCheck::fooCheck()
{
    std::cout << "blah blah" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "ctor"<< std::endl;    
}

int fooCheck::fooFS(){   <- I want this to be startred as a thread
    some code
    return 1;
}
```

my header file

```
    class fooCheck
{
    public:
        fooCheck();
        int fooFS();
    private:
};

#endif
```

and my main() cpp file ...

```
#include stuff_stuff_stuff
#include "fooCheck.h"

int main()
{
    ICMP_check foo_acces_object;
    foo_acces_object.fooFS();
}
```

So the placed object works fine and executes the function from the class.
I would like the function from the class started and executed as a thread.
What I tried is:
    std::thread tt1{foo_check::fooFS()}; 
    std::thread tt1{fooFS()};  
Any advice on how to move this forward ?

Comment: There's no simple answer to this. Start and join the threads where it makes sense, this has nothing to do with classes or anything.

Comment: hi - added some code concept of mine ... Can you take a look and advise ?

Comment: Again, the answer does not depend in any way on your class structure. The really important thing is a) what you replaced with `some code` (etc.) and b) a description what the program should do.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have come up with a pattern for running c++ threads that have the same life cycle as the class the thread is a part of. It is basically a threading pattern for c++ classes, and it avoids some common problems when using c++ threads.

http://blog.chrisd.info/how-to-run-threads/